# Let A $\subset \mathbb{R}$. Show using induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, if |A|=n then A is bounded

Tags: induction, bounded-variation

```
The conditional statement is P(n), given by,
```

$$P(n):\forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{if} \ |A|=n \ \text{then} \ A \ \text{is bounded}$$
    The base case is when $n=1$. Thus $A=\{a_0\}$ where $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. $|\{a_0\}|=1=n$. Therefore, our base case is bounded by $M>1$.\
    The inductive assumption. I will assume that $k$ is fixed and that $P(k)$ is true. That is, assume $|A|=k$ and $A$ is bounded.
$$$$
    The inductive step. Now I will demonstrate that also $P(k+1)$ is true. I must establish that $|A|$ is bounded.There are two cases. Suppose that all sets of cardinality $|k-1|$ are bounded. Let $A$ be any set of size $k$. Take a subcollection of $|k-1|$ elements. We are left with one element and our two cases. The element is k and the cases are when, cardinality of $A$ is equal to k and when the cardinality of $A$ is not equal to k. Below we will examine the two cases,
    \begin{align*}
   \text{ Case one:} |A|=k\\
    \text{Let} \ B
\end{align*}
    I'm still struggling to figure out how to use cardinality with induction and to determine the two cases Andres mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Base: $\{a_0\}$ is clearly bounded.

**Induction hint:**: There are two cases. Suppose that all sets of cardinality 
$|n-1|$ are bounded. Let $A$ be any set of size $n$. Take a subcollection of $n-1$ elements. There is one element left over and two cases, what are they?

Comment: The one element left over is n and the two cases is when n positive and n negative?

Comment: negative or positive should be inconsequential. Consider the set $A=\{1,\pi,3\}$. It is clearly bounded. In particular $|a| \leq \pi$ for each $a \in A$. What happens if we add some real number to the set? What are the possibilities? For example,, if we add $-e$ to the set, then what is the set bounded by? What if we added $1000$ as an element in the set?

Comment: I believe that A is bounded by n, but I don't know how to prove that using induction or any other method at this current time.

Comment: @RonDurga then this is the wrong question. The correct one should be "understanding the definition of induction," the answer to which I'm sure can be found on this website in many posts.